# Add firebase cloud messaging support without gradle or android studio assistant

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add firebase support to an existing application.

I followed the documentation ([Firebase and android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)) but everything is about gradle.

The app i'm working with was made on Intellij and I don't have gradle on my project, It would be a little bit tricky to migrate to another IDE.

So here is my question, can I add firebase cloud messaging support without gradle ? I have some libraries included in my project under .jar files but I wasn't able to find any .jar files for firebase (and I guess there is some dependencies)

Edit: I found this: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate

Comment: Android studio also uses intellij so should not be difficult to migrate

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to integrate firebase without Gradle file. For that, there is three way to integrate firebase without Gradle. But, I suggest you, to migrate Android Studio from IntelliJ developer tool.

Still, you do not want to migrate three ways are as below:

1. Copy firebase SDK in your project and then use it as you want. Download firebase SDK for Android from below link.

[Download Firebase SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk)

Note: It's not a good way to integrate firebase SDK into your project. Because when you use the above way then it will be about specific version SDK which will difficult to update with a new version after a long time for an application update you are trying.

2. Use Maven to integrate firebase in your project. For taking maven for firebase SDK go to below link. From below link, you will find different maven for a different product by Firebase.

[Firebase SDK Mavan](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase)

Note: I am not sure about using maven in an android project will work properly or not. But you should have to try because of its easy way to update the new version of firebase SDK when new update available.

3. Add AAR file in your project. AAR file is same as a JAR file. So, you have to include AAR file which you can find from the above link for maven. For every product, there is a separate AAR file which you have to download and integrate it.

Note: I am not sure about to integrate AAR file in your project will work or not. But you should have to try to integrate it. It's also easy to update when new update available.

Comment: can you elaborate how to use the 1st method?

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give you is to move your build to Gradle. You can then build your project from all IDEs including IntelliJ and also on the command line.