# Add Firebase in a non Gradle Android project

Tags: android, firebase, chromium

I want to add Firebase Analytics in my Android project but the problem is that all off the documentation I found usees Gradle and my project (which is based on Chromium project) does not use Gradle.

Do you have any idea how can I do this? Thx.

Comment: Check this answer, maybe helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53631533/5919525